# Usage of wp_send_json_success and wp_redirect at the same time

Tags: ajax, redirect, json, authentication, authorization

I have to send the success response to ajax if user filled the form fields successfully or not on the client side and redirect to the other page which finalize his authorization at the same time on the server side.

Is it possible to implement somehow? What alternatives do I have?

Comment: I tink it is not possible. If you redirect the user in first place, **where do you send the ajax response back?**. In the other hand, `wp_send_json_success` performs a `die()` after the response has been sent, so you can't execute `wp_redirect` after `wp_send_json_success`. I think the choices are 1) send the ajax response and make the redirection client side; 2) send ajax response, then make a new ajax request and then make the redirection server side; or 3) don't send ajax response and make the redirection server side;

Comment: You can't do both. Redirection cannot happen if you're also sending back a result.